# Controlling the Display Order of Map Tips for Overlapping Features

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, order, maptips

I have a point layer with multiple overlapping features. I have managed to control the rendering order of these features on the map using the "Control feature rendering order" option in the Symbology tab of Layer Properties. I've used fields such as 'fid' and a specific 'date' field to set this order.

However, this rendering order doesn't seem to influence the order in which features are displayed when using map tips. Specifically, I want the map tip to display only the feature that was added last (i.e., the one with the highest 'fid' or the most recent date).

Despite my attempts to control the rendering order, the map tip doesn't seem to reflect this preference. Is there a way to ensure that the map tip displays only the last added feature or the one with the highest 'fid'?